# Retrieve the number on subscriber

Tags: mysql, sql

I've two tables, Table1(News) and Table2(Subscribers).

Table1: id, news_title

Table2: id, news_id, user_id

```
Table1
id | news_title
--------------
 1 | News 1
 2 | News 2
 3 | news 3

Table2
id | news_title_id | user_id
----------------------------
 1 | 1             | 1
 2 | 1             | 2
 3 | 2             | 3
```

I need a query result like this.

```
news_title | subscribers
------------------------
News 1     | 2
News 2     | 1
News 3     | 0
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple aggregate `COUNT(*)` with a `LEFT JOIN` will do the job here.  `LEFT JOIN` and `COUNT(*)` (rather than `COUNT(user_id)`) are used to be sure titles with zero subscribers still return a row.

```
SELECT 
  news_title,
  COUNT(Table2.*) AS subscribers
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id = Table2.news_title_id
GROUP BY news.title
```